# Why is the created T-SQL function duplicating data?

Tags: sql-server, function

I am new to this so I apologise in advance if I haven't followed forum protocol!

I am trying to create a function in T-SQL which calculates the GST of a product's price based on two parameters; the `ProductID` and the `GST_Percentage` 
(which is 10%).

If you inspect the image attached of my current output results you will see my problem. I am expecting a single record to be returned as I have only entered one `ProductID` as an input parameter BUT instead all the records in the table are returned AND the expected calculated GST for the `ProductID` entered is correct but it is also displayed for all the unwanted records.

I have tried for hours to figure out what I am doing wrong but don't seem able to figure it out. Please help

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_CalculateGST 
    (@ProductID INT,
     @GST_Percentage FLOAT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Price MONEY

    SET @Price = (SELECT Price
                  FROM Products
                  WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)

    RETURN @Price * @GST_Percentage
END
GO
```

Below is the `SELECT` statement I used to test the function.

```
SELECT  
    ProductID, ProductDescription, 
    Price, dbo.fn_CalculateGST(1, 0.10) AS GST 
FROM    
    Products
```

Output results:

[image]

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Your query, the SELECT that is your last code example, does not have a `WHERE` clause, so it will return all products in the `Products` table, and for each such product your function will return. That function will, for that row, return *something* related to product id 1. However, it will do so for each product. In short, your final SQL will also need a `WHERE` clause limiting it to only including one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're **always** passing `1` as your first parameter (`@ProductID`) into your function in your `SELECT` statement - so it will **always** calculate 10% of 15.00 - which is 1.50 - so the output **IS** correct!

But you probably wanted something like this:

```
SELECT
    ProductID, ProductDescription,
    Price, dbo.fn_CalculateGST(ProductID, 0.10) AS GST
    --                         ********* pass in ProductID - not always 1 !!!!
FROM
    Products
```

See: you need to pass in `ProductID` column value into your function - not always 1 .....